# Error "Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable" in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, compiling, 64-bit, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have modified some code from ARToolkit in MacOS and now I need to compile it with Windows subsystem (Ubuntu). I have followed the [ARToolkit user manual](https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit-docs/blob/master/8_Advanced_Topics/build_artoolkit.md) instruction and have installed all libraries to compile with Ubuntu.

Here's my makefile :

```
INC_DIR= ../../include
LIB_DIR= ../../lib
BIN_DIR= .

CC=cc
LDFLAG= -L$(LIB_DIR)
LIBS= $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv) -lARgsub -lARvideo -lAR -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework CoreFoundation 
CFLAG= $(shell pkg-config --cflags opencv) -O -I$(INC_DIR) -Wno-deprecated-declarations 

OBJS = SOIL2/SOIL2.o SOIL2/etc1_utils.o SOIL2/image_DXT.o SOIL2/image_helper.o
HEADDERS =

all: $(BIN_DIR)/simple $(BIN_DIR)/simple2

$(BIN_DIR)/simple: simple.o $(OBJS)
    ${CC} -o $(BIN_DIR)/simple simple.o $(OBJS) $(LDFLAG) $(LIBS)


$(BIN_DIR)/simple2: simple2.o $(OBJS)
    ${CC} -o $(BIN_DIR)/simple2 simple2.o $(OBJS) $(LDFLAG) $(LIBS)


simple.o: simple.c $(HEADDERS)
    ${CC} $(CFLAG) -c simple.c

simple2.o: simple2.c $(HEADDERS)
    ${CC} $(CFLAG) -c simple2.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(BIN_DIR)/simple
    rm -f $(BIN_DIR)/simple2

allclean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(BIN_DIR)/simple
    rm -f $(BIN_DIR)/simple2
    rm -f Makefile
```

Now that I can compile using makefile successfully, when I try to run my program I encountered error :

```
./simple: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Then I checked with file command :

```
Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable, flags:<NOUNDEFS|DYLDLINK|TWOLEVEL|PIE>
```

And my machine is this :

```
Linux Raisa 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #285-Microsoft Thu Aug 30 17:31:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And I also have read posts here :

1. [Can I run a binary file that is Mach-O executable i386 on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205986/can-i-run-a-binary-file-that-is-mach-o-executable-i386-on-linux) (asked in 2010)
2. [What are the alternatives for running a Mach-O 64-bit binary file on a linux machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505163/what-are-the-alternatives-for-running-a-mach-o-64-bit-binary-file-on-a-linux-mac) (asked in 2017)

and basically both of them stated that there's really nothing we can do about it. Does this still apply ? This is the first time I need to switch between OS when compiling a program, and I'm not familiar with this. If I should edit part which specific part I need to modify ?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! If you have the source code of the program, configure it for your system and rebuild for it. That’s all we can tell generally. To get specific advice, could you share your Makefile, for example?

Comment: @Melebius hi, I've updated my question and added my makefile. Would you please take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: Does your `cc` point to a non-native compiler? what does `type -a cc` say?